# Query regarding dependency Injection in PHP

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, loose-coupling

I've been reading up on dependency injection and I think I pretty much understand the concepts, including constructor injection and setter injection.

However, I am unsure what I would do in the following scenario:

Say I have a class that has many methods, but **only one** of those methods requires a certain other object. How do I go about providing this object to the method? Should I not just directly pass the object to method as a parameter like so:

```
class aClass
{
    function aMethod(anotherClass $anotherClass)
    {
        anotherClass->hello();
    }

    function otherMethods()
    {
    }
    .....
}
```

The other option would be to provide it to the entire class, which seems unnecessary. like so:

```
class aClass
{
    protected $_anotherClass;

    function aMethod()
    {
        anotherClass->hello();
    }

    function otherMethods()
    {
    }
    .....

    function setAnotherClass(anotherClass $anotherClass)
    {
            $this->_anotherClass;
    }
}
```

When should I pass an object to a method and when should I use dependency injection via constructors/setters?
Is there a rule of thumb or a best practice for when to use one of these two options?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It would be easier to anwer your question if your example was more concrete. What is `anotherClass` and what does aMethod do with it?

Comment: Okay, one scenario: I have a Basket class in my e-commerce website. One of the methods in this Basket class is called listProducts(). This is the only method which requires access to the database table of products. This has it's own data mapper class called productsMapper.

Second scenario: I have a data mapper class with a save() method. This method requires a model of the row. Providing this model to the entire class makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Okay, I find this very intuitively, so here concrete answers. First scenario: inject -- the basket may make a few DB requests. Second scenario: parameter, you only need the data once to store and may want to store other models using the same object's function.

Comment: @middus Great, that's really helpful and what I was thinking as well. Yeah it is quite intuitive but I do like following rules, possibly due to mild OCD! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned a rule of thumb, so here it is:

**Ask yourself the question:** *could someone legitimately call this method twice on the same object, providing different values for the argument in the two calls?*

If yes, then leave it as a parameter. If no, then it's a good candidate for injection as you describe.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dxe1x2.aspx) is a good example of a method of the first type, where removing the parameter and injecting a dependency in the class instead would be a really bad idea. C# instead of PHP, but you get the picture.

Comment: Ah this does make a lot of sense, thank you. Especially with Data Mappers. Does leaving it as a parameter reduce the ease with which I can unit test? I haven't actually ever tried to unit test anything yet by the way!

Comment: @Azriel: Of course not. The only thing that reduces your capability to unit test is hardcoding types.

Comment: I like your example, simple and to the point. By hardcoding types I assume you mean having $anotherClass = new anotherClass() within the aMethod() method?

Answer (score 1):

The internal workings of a class are no-ones business but that class itself. If only one function requires the dependency then so be it.

Alternatively you could wonder why only one function has the dependency, is you class maybe doing two separate things?

The only reason you wouldn't want to inject dependencies in the constructor is when the cost of making that resource is very high (ready a large file on disk, connecting to remote host etc.), but even in that case, you could pass in a 'proxy' or 'deferred' object as a 'promise' that you can get to the dependency if you ever need it.

Comment: But there are certain scenarios like, for example, a Data Mapper that inserts a model of a database row into a database. Even on the Zend QuickStart guide I see this:
    public function save(Application_Model_Guestbook $guestbook)
    {
    }

Is this not valid?

Comment: @Azriel Of course it is, because it is a parameter. If you want to save something, you'll need to know what to save.

Comment: @middus that's precisely the very point I was making! I just thought it conflicted with what was given in this answer.